# What is this syntax? var x == ( enum | enum)

Tags: c#, syntax, operators

I've come across this code snippet (that works) and I'm curious as to what the syntax is.

```
if (keyData == (Keys.Control | Keys.F)) {
    MessageBox.Show("What the Ctrl+F?");
  }
```

I've searched for

> | Operator C#

but this merely results in links to the `||` OR operator.

My inital thoughts are that this could be shorthand for `if (keydata == keys.Control || keydata == Keys.F)` (syntax I would love to see in C#7) but this doesn't seem to be the case.

Could anyone please explain this to me?

Comment: Bitwise OR: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17zwb64t.aspx

Comment: Also, that syntax shortcut you wanted already exists with unary operators.             bool x = keydata == keys.Control || keydata == keys.F ? MessageBox.Show("What the Ctrl + F?") : DoThisIfFalse();

Comment: @user1895086 that's not a shortcut? You've had to type `keydata ==` twice? The shortcut would be `bool x = keydata == (keys.Control||keys.f)`